# Meteor files naming convention that will prevent it from processing?

Tags: meteor

Is there anything I can do to temporarily turn off some files in my project tree without commenting lines inside of it? (and without deleting it as well)?

I've heard only about file order but nothing about ignore convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a documented one. But you could just rename them to `filename._js`

Comment: One disadvantage is that IDE (WebStorm for example) losing its syntax highlights. But you can set it back manually, yes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Kriegslustig has a great option. Another viable option is to drag those files to the `test` folder, which meteor ignores.